# How to use localhost TileServer GL in leaflet map in L.tileLayer?

Tags: leaflet, gis, openstreetmap, offline

**I am trying to make offline maps using leaflet and Tileserver Gl**

Im trying to load Tileserver Gl tiles[Which is hosted in my Local system of an particular region which is Sri Lanka] in my application where in have used Leaflet to plot map.
But tiles are not loading and i'm not able to figure it out.
Will add the code which is used to plot my map

**Locally hosted my tiles using following code**

```
npm install -g tileserver-gl-light
tileserver-gl-light sri_lanka.mbtiles
```

**Online Working Map-**

```
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

**Offline Map**

Which is not loading the tiles

```
L.tileLayer('http://localhost:8080/data/v3/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

**Info :** Im bit new to leaflet and programming, Im struck in this for past 2 days
Thanx in advance!

Comment: You have read the documentation at https://tileserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints.html#rendered-tiles , right?

Comment: yeah with tat i continued still having issues in loading tiles offline. Im new 2 leaflet. What might be the reason of not able to load tiles.Your Inputs might help me to proceed. 
Thanks @IvanSanchez

Comment: Have you checked if the local tile server is running? Does opening `http://localhost:8080/data/v3/0/0/0.png` work or show anything when you open it in a browser? Any Javascript console errors on your map, "file not found", etc.?

Comment: yeah checked that link. getting error "Invalid format". and this is console error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". What might be the reason Thanks @chki

Comment: @chrki While pointing "http://localhost:8080/data/v3/0/0/0.pbf" link im able to download the .pbf file.

Comment: Oh, I see it now, you are using a tileserver that servers **vector tiles** and not image tiles. You'll need to use a Leaflet plugin for that: http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#vector-tiles **Edit**: Have you tried the "static images" URLs from the documentation?

Comment: I have downloded vector tiles from http://osm2vectortiles.org/downloads/ and used that mbtiles for serving tiles. Let me go thrw that link which is shared. 
Thanks @Chrki

Comment: there are lots of plugins available in mentioned link under different buckets . Can you do share me the plugin name so as could use that to load image tiles in my application using mdtiles. Thanks @chrki

Comment: I'll have to correct myself, these URLs work by default with that server, no need for plugins: `http://localhost:8080/styles/klokantech-basic/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` and `http://localhost:8080/styles/osm-bright/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `/data/v3` endpoint of TileServer GL Light does not serve PNG image tiles but vector tiles in the Protobuf (pbf) format.

For Leaflet you will have to use a plugin, some are listed in the [Leaflet Documentation](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#vector-tiles). Some more suggestions and sample code can be found on this GIS Stackexchange question: [How to load a vector tile layer in a Leaflet map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190390/how-to-load-a-vector-tile-layer-in-a-leaflet-map).

Only the "non-light" TileServer GL has "rendered tiles". If you are using that you can access tiles using one of the following URLs (with the standard styles provided):

```
http://localhost:8080/styles/klokantech-basic/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
http://localhost:8080/styles/osm-bright/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

You'll also find these on http://localhost:8080/ after you have started TileServer GL.

Comment: while using one of the links 
http://localhost:8080/styles/klokantech-basic/{z}/{x}/{y}.pn‌​g
http://localhost:8080/styles/osm-bright/{z}/{x}/{y}.png 
Im geeing empty tiles.Ur statement was so clear but im committing some mistakes doing this POC. Not able to visualise  Thanks

Comment: There was some weird invisible space in the first URL, I fixed it now, sorry

Comment: I have corrected my URL and getting empty gray screen in "styles" for rendered maps: Klokantech Basic and OSM Bright. Tiles are still not loaded but tile server is running. @chrki thanks

Comment: what might be the changes needed http://plnkr.co/edit/PNsZc9JxXuzhxTAn6LgC?p=preview
To work offline map. 
   L.tileLayer('http://localhost:8080/data/v3/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
Thanks @chrki

Comment: Can you send a link to the sri_lanka.mbtiles file? You probably just have to change the URL in line 27. If your map tiles are empty/gray your data might be broken or empty, I tested the Zurich file linked on the TileServer GL website, worked fine.

Comment: I got the tiles from following URL.  
https://openmaptiles.org/downloads/#country
used **tileserver-gl-light sri_lanka.mdtiles** to run local server for sri lanka data. Thanks in advance for being so kind hearted.

Comment: I accidentally installed `tileserver-gl` instead of `tileserver-gl-light`... that might be why it works here... let me check and re-do my answer

Comment: I tried doing all the known  things and also with ur inputs. Still gray screen persists while trying offlne map but in online its working fine.
I will try in tileserver-gl instead tileserver-gl-light.

Comment: Check the example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/PLKuyGVUmxx0Wa3gEsOC?p=preview I added the `leaflet-mapbox-vector-tile` plugin, the styling needs to be done if you want it to look differently. It might be a good idea to upgrade to Leaflet 1.0 as well eventually. Some more suggestions on how to work with Leaflet + Vector tiles on [GIS Stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190390/how-to-load-a-vector-tile-layer-in-a-leaflet-map)

Comment: Styling thing will look into next. I'm into leaflet for past 2 days. Reason y faced ths issue.
Thanks for all inputs and time.!!!  finally was able to load map offline for an particular region. :) :) :) @chrki